# What is the volume of the parallelepiped at $ \ t=1 \ $?

Tags: calculus

A time dependent parallelepiped , P(t) , with its base in $ \ x-y \ $ plane is determined by vectors  $ \ (0,2t,t ) , \ (0,t,-t), \ (t,0,t^2 ) \ $.

What is the volume of the parallelepiped at $ \ t=1 \ $ ?

The options:

(i) $ \ 16 \ $

(ii) $ 17 \ $

(iii) $ \ 18 \ $

(iv) $ \ 19 $

**Answer:**

At $ \ t=1 \ $

$ (0,2t,t)=(0,2,1)=\vec u , say , \\ (0,t,-t)=(0,1,-1)=\vec v , say \\ (t,0,t^2)=(1,0,1)=\vec w , say \ $

Thus the volume of the parallelepiped is

$ \vec u \cdot (\vec v \times \vec w )=-3 \ $

which does not match any option .

Help me doing this

Comment: Your first vector should be $(0,2,1)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: correct, but the triple product [reflects that.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((0,1,-1)+cross+(1,0,1))+dot+(0,2,1))

Comment: what would be the option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct even if, to determine the volume, we should consider the absolute value that is $$|\vec u \cdot (\vec v \times \vec w )|=3$$

Another unclear point is that the OP is asking for a parallelepipid with its base in $x-y$ plane but the parallepiped $P(t)$ has not base in that's plane.